# automatic repaint when minimizing window

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, jpanel, paint

I have a JFrame, with two panels, in one panel I draw a line, as I was working I minimized the Window of the java program i'm doing, when i maximized it THE LINE THAT I DREW WAS DIFFERENT, it repainted it in a different place!

Does anyone have an idea of how to lock the painting so that when i minimize it doesn't screw the drawing??

Thank you!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;


class JFramePaint1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener /*implements ActionListener*/{

    public static int activa = 0;
    public static JButton drawing = new JButton("drawing");
    public static JButton erase = new JButton("erase");
    public static int x1=0, y1=0,x2=0,y2=0;

   public JFramePaint1(){
                                                    //row column
      JPanel container = new JPanel(); //new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
      JPanel header = new JPanel();
    //  header.setLayout(new GridLayout(50, 2));
    // header.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     header.setLayout(new BoxLayout(header, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
     container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); //lo quite ahorita
     // container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

     ContentComponent c = new ContentComponent();

      drawing.addActionListener(this);
      erase.addActionListener(this);

    //header.setSize(30,30);

     //drawing.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
     container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 0)));

     header.add(drawing); //lo quite ahorita
     header.add(erase);
     container.add(header);
    //container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
    //header.add(drawing);

      // container.add(header);
      container.add(c);   //lo quite ahorita

      add(container);

    //  add(c);
       //add(c);
   }
   public static void main(String[] a) {

        JFramePaint1 VentanaDiverti = new JFramePaint1();
        VentanaDiverti.setSize(800, 700);
        VentanaDiverti.setLocation(200, 0);
        VentanaDiverti.setTitle("Diverti");
        VentanaDiverti.setResizable ( false );
        VentanaDiverti.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        VentanaDiverti.setVisible(true);

    /* JFrame f = new JFrame();
    // JFramePaint1 f = new JFramePaint1();
       f.setTitle("Drawing Graphics in Frames");
        f.setSize(800, 650);
        f.setLocation(200,50);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        f.setContentPane( new ContentComponent());
        f.getContentPane().add(b);

        //f.addWindowListener(this);
        //b.addActionListener(this);


        f.setVisible(true);*/

   }
   static class ContentComponent extends JPanel {

     public void paint(Graphics g) {

         BufferedImage image;
         /*reset the variables, this makes the repaint look the same! it's as comments so that you can see what happens
         x1=0;
            y1=0;
            x2=0;
            y2=0;
        */
       try {                
          image = ImageIO.read(new File("image name and path"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
       }


         g.setColor (Color.RED);
         // void    fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
         // Fills the specified rectangle.
         g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
         if( activa == 1){

         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // g.drawRect(40, 40, 150, 80);
         int x = 40;
         int y= 40;
         for(int i = 0; i< 4; i++){

            //g.drawRect(x+10, y+10, 150, 80);
            x = x+10;
            y = y+10;
         }
         //drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
         //Draws a line, between the points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) in this graphics context's coordinate system.
           x1+=20;
           x2+=20;
           y2+=50;
           g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
           x2+=30;
           y1=y2;
           g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
          // g.drawLine(20,0,20,50);

         }
        // activa = 0;

      }//del paint
   }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          if(e.getSource()== drawing)
        {   System.out.println("entro");
           if(activa==0){
            activa = 1;

            repaint();}

        }
        if(e.getSource()==erase){
            activa = 0;
            x1=0;
            y1=0;
            x2=0;
            y2=0;
            repaint();
        }
      }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
     {

        System.exit(0);

     }
     public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e){}

     public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){}

     public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e){}

     public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e){}

     public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){}

     public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){}  
}
```

Comment: ok I've solved it by adding the initial coordinates of the line right inside the paint method, so it draws the line in the exact same place after I maximized the window, so it makes it look like nothing happened. But if anybody knows how to lock it i would still like to know.

Comment: You are not being very clear with what you want?  What do you mean by 'lock it'?

Comment: Not repaint when i minimize window. If i minimize the window and then maximize it, i don't see the initial drawing, the line appears in a different place. I draw the line like this  x1+=20;
     x2+=20;
     y2+=50;
     g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2); Initial values of all coordinates are 0. These x1 etc are global variables, so that's why it repaints it in a different place when i minimize it...I think it is not normal for the program to auto paint when i minimized it and then maximized it.

Comment: Could you give us a full example of your source?  I might be able to give you a hint if I had some more knowledge of what your code looks like.  My intuition is that with the += modifiers, every time you repaint, it's actually recalculating the position of the line.  It's just that the repaint isn't as often as you think it's actually happening.

Comment: there's the code right after the paint i included the solution that i mentioned that ocurred to me after i posted! but it seems silly to have to reset variables because when i minimize it automatically repaints!!

Comment: Custom painting should be done in the paintComponent(...) method and you should invoke super.paintComponent(...);

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is not normal for the program to auto paint when i minimized it and then maximized it.

It is very normal for this to happen. The `paint` method can be called at *any time*, whenever the system needs to redraw a portion of your window (see [Painting in AWT](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#awt) for specific details). When you minimize the window, whatever you drew into it before is *not saved* anywhere, so when you maximize the window, all of the contents need to be drawn again, so `paint` will be called automatically.

For this reason, you should not perform any updates to your data in `paint`. You should do these in a separate method, store the results in your variables and *only use* these existing results to draw the content.

Since the following parts do not change:

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("image name and path"));
x1+=20;
x2+=20;
y2+=50;
x2+=30;
```

move them into a separate method, say `updatePoints`. Then in your `actionPerformed` method, first call `updatePoints()` and then `repaint()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a window listener to your jframe that calls the panels paint method when a resize/maximize/whatever event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just to add to what casablanca said, what is happening is that since your x1, x2, y1, y2 variables are static, they are getting updated every time you perform a paint, and then staying at that value until the next repaint, at which time they are updated again, etc...

My recommendation would actually be to separate your data from your display code.  So, instead of having x1, x2, y1, and y2 declared as static global variables, have them part of the inner class (what you call ContentComponent, and have a starting x1, x2, y1, y2 values as your global variables, like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

class JFramePaint1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener /*implements ActionListener*/{

  public static int activa = 0;
  public static JButton drawing = new JButton("drawing");
  public static JButton erase = new JButton("erase");
  public static final int sx1 = 0, sy1 = 0, sx2 = 0, sy2 = 0;

  public JFramePaint1() {
    //row column
    JPanel container = new JPanel(); //new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    JPanel header = new JPanel();
    //  header.setLayout(new GridLayout(50, 2));
    // header.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    header.setLayout(new BoxLayout(header, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); //lo quite ahorita
    // container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    ContentComponent c = new ContentComponent();

    drawing.addActionListener(this);
    erase.addActionListener(this);

    //header.setSize(30,30);

    //drawing.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
    container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 0)));

    header.add(drawing); //lo quite ahorita
    header.add(erase);
    container.add(header);
    //container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
    //header.add(drawing);

    // container.add(header);
    container.add(c); //lo quite ahorita

    add(container);

    //  add(c);
    //add(c);
  }

  public static void main(String[] a) {

    JFramePaint1 VentanaDiverti = new JFramePaint1();
    VentanaDiverti.setSize(800, 700);
    VentanaDiverti.setLocation(200, 0);
    VentanaDiverti.setTitle("Diverti");
    VentanaDiverti.setResizable(false);
    VentanaDiverti.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    VentanaDiverti.setVisible(true);

    /* JFrame f = new JFrame();
    // JFramePaint1 f = new JFramePaint1();
       f.setTitle("Drawing Graphics in Frames");
        f.setSize(800, 650);
        f.setLocation(200,50);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        f.setContentPane( new ContentComponent());
        f.getContentPane().add(b);

        //f.addWindowListener(this);
        //b.addActionListener(this);


        f.setVisible(true);*/

  }
  static class ContentComponent extends JPanel {

    static int x1, x2, y1, y2;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
      x1 = sx1;
      x2 = sx2;
      y1 = sy1;
      y2 = sy2;

//      BufferedImage image;
      /*reset the variables, this makes the repaint look the same! it's as comments so that you can see what happens
      x1=0;
         y1=0;
         x2=0;
         y2=0;
      */
//      try {
//        image = ImageIO.read(new File("image name and path"));
//      } catch(IOException ex) {
//        // handle exception...
//      }

      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      // void    fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
      // Fills the specified rectangle.
      g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
      if(activa == 1) {

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // g.drawRect(40, 40, 150, 80);
        int x = 40;
        int y = 40;
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

          //g.drawRect(x+10, y+10, 150, 80);
          x = x + 10;
          y = y + 10;
        }
        //drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
        //Draws a line, between the points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) in this graphics context's coordinate system.
        x1 += 20;
        x2 += 20;
        y2 += 50;
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        x2 += 30;
        y1 = y2;
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        // g.drawLine(20,0,20,50);

      }
      // activa = 0;

    }//del paint
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == drawing) {
      System.out.println("entro");
      if(activa == 0) {
        activa = 1;

        repaint();
      }

    }
    if(e.getSource() == erase) {
      activa = 0;
      repaint();
    }
  }

  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

    System.exit(0);

  }

  public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}

  public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}

  public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}

  public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}

  public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}

  public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
}
```